# Select data binding for an object

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a strange behavior when binding the following object to a `select`:

```
REGIONSH = {0:"All Regions",1:"Europe",2:"North America"};
```

HTML (where `region` is a integer for key):

```
<select ng-model="REGIONSH[region]" ng-options="name for(key,name) in REGIONSH">
```

The behavior is that the list is populated correctly with the correct option selected, but when I change the `region` variable the selected entry changes fine, but suddenly both the original and the new selections are named the same thing.

For example, I would select the second element in the list, and the original one would be renamed to "North America" from "All Regions".

The desired behavior is to have a select where I can chose from each of the values in the object while having the key as the `option`'s value.

Comment: Also if I try setting `ng-model` to just the integer (which happens to also be the index) I just get an empty option with `?` as the value.

Comment: I think you're using `ng-model` recursively, whereas it should maybe just be `ng-model="region"`. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sR2rv8F5p37OHYkCHNb3?p=preview) is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @MorganDelaney The region variable is an integer that refers to a key in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your html:

```
<select ng-model="REGIONSH[region]" ng-options="name for(key,name) in REGIONSH">
```

It will display the list correctly, but whenever the user makes a choice the `name` of the region ("`name for(key,name)`") will be bound to wherever `ng-model` is pointing to.

Meaning when the user makes a choice for say the first option, it `ng-model` will effectively perform

```
REGIONSH[region] = /*name of the selected region*/;
```

Which assigns a name to the region at index `region`.

What you probably want is `ng-model="region"`, so the values are assigned to the `region` variable, and not the options. ( Or any other variable you want to store the choice in; probably not in `REGIONSH` though )

Then you'd also need `ng-options="key as name for (key, name) in REGIONSH`, so that it still displays the name, but now assigns `key` whenever the user makes a selection. ( [Read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage) on the many `ng-options` formats you can use )

Meaning when a selection is made it performs

```
region = /*key of the selected region*/;
```

The final result would be

```
<select ng-model="region" ng-options="key as name for(key,name) in REGIONSH">
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this now, the thing is - when I set the region it immediately flips back to the `?` option. I'm using the exact thing you have at the end of your answer. The `region` variable refers to a key in the object.

Comment: @ChristianStewart I've slightly modified another commenters plunkr, [here's a working sample of the above code](http://plnkr.co/edit/RZYjm8gnOA9bK2mnfE8d?p=preview). You might need the additional `option` tag depending on how ancient your browser is

Comment: I don't need the initial option because the `region` variable will ALWAYS be a key in the object. I'm still getting the empty select option with `?` as a key though.

Comment: @ChristianStewart I hope you're looking at the same thing because [this is what i'm getting](http://imgur.com/Iy3K5lP). Could you post the code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Alright this is strange, I made a plunker that does the same thing as well, and it works, but in my app it doesn't. I'm streaming it here: http://twitch.tv/quantumdota

Comment: I suppose I'll leave it unbound for now. It's a strange glitch.